# Using regular expressions to select all uppercase words until the first lowercase character

Tags: regex, regular-language

I am working on an online dictionary.

Currently I have all of my entries contained in a data array.

Example: "WORD ENTRY IN ONE LANGUAGE the same word in another language"

What I want to do is select all of the uppercase characters until the first next non-capital letter (may be a number, may be a parenthesis, etc., but is generally a lowercase letter).

I am currently trying to use a regex, but I have not had any luck!

Comment: Wouldn't [A-Z ]* do the trick? Captures all uppercase letters and spaces

Comment: @HexedAgain only problem is that other uppercase characters will show up in the middle of lowercase letters when it is a proper name i.e China etc

Comment: Please show us a representative sample where (ideally) all your edge cases occur.

Comment: Try [`^[^a-z]*`](https://regex101.com/r/nT2pR4/1).

Comment: I guess you should include an anchor for the start of the string `^[A-Z ]*`

Comment: Which regex flavor do you use?

Answer (score 1):

If the regex flavor is C#:

```
^\p{Lu}+(?:\s+\p{Lu}+)*\b
```

Comment: Add `^` to the beginning and `\b` to the end and I'll upvote.  `\p{Lu}` will also work in several other flavors, but the main thing is the structure of the regex, matching one or more all-uppercase *words*.

Comment: The `\b` at the end is necessary because without it, the hypothetical entry `ODIN Wotan` would yield the match `ODIN W`.  I know the OP said the next character after the match would be lowercase or not a letter, but where's the challenge in that?  Initial capitals in the definition is the only thing that makes this problem interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Match all leading (anchored to start) uppercase letters and the space:

```
^[A-Z ]+
```

This simple expression will work in every regex flavor I can think of.

To not match trailing space(s) of the target:

```
^[A-Z ]*?(?= *[^A-Z])
```